# connectionrefused error in android

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, web-services

i tried retrieved data from mysql database using soap websevices in android.but i got one error on my emulator.the error is ERROR:java.net.connectionException:/192.168.1.249-connection refused.my ip address is correct...then y dis error is came..plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/ari` says that you are running the database server on your android device; I would guess not.

Comment: So, your database is located on the device? I was not aware of a mysql for android. All tutorials for mysql connection from android show a middle layer that the device connects to, the middle layer connects to the database, gets the response and sends this back to the phone.